# How to make markdown-live-priview-mode use pandoc?

Tags: customize, markdown-mode, pandoc

I'm having a problem where in `markdown-live-preview-mode` tables are not correctly converted to HTML from markdown. I'm using [markdown-mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/). I've tried using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to create the HTML and pandoc correctly produces the table. I would like to set markdown-mode to use pandoc to create the HTML file for the live preview.

I get this from current markdown-live:

```
| Page Type | Description | |:-----------:|:---------------------------------------------------------:| | Stand-alone |
about or static text | | Referance | Index lookup page wit likns of all blog pasts or products | |
periodical | Blog posts or writing column, any series |
```

If I do `M-!` [return] `pandoc -s -o filename.html filename.md` [return]. [position cursor on `eww` buffer] `g`.

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th style="text-align: center;">Page Type</th>
<th style="text-align: center;">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td style="text-align: center;">Stand-alone</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">about or static text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td style="text-align: center;">Referance</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">Index lookup page wit likns of all blog pasts or products</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td style="text-align: center;">periodical</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">Blog posts or writing column, any series</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

*It doesn't work on stackexchange; markdown tables. After running `pandoc` the output is correct in `filename.html`*

I'm thinking there is a way to customize the command that markdown-mode uses to convert markdown to HTML in emacs init file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the settings I use:

```lisp
(setq markdown-command
      (concat
       "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"
       " --from=markdown --to=html"
       " --standalone --mathjax --highlight-style=pygments"
       " --css=pandoc.css"
       " --quiet"
       " --number-sections"
       " --lua-filter=lua.lua"
       " --metadata-file=metadata.yml"
       " --metadata=reference-section-title:'References & Further Reading'"
       " --filter pandoc-citeproc"
       " --bibliography=bibfile.bib"
       ))
```

This lets me open an html file that is generated via pandoc